# Get the location of a MySQL restore database file

Tags: mysql, .net, vb.net

I have a VB.NET project with a MySQL database.
I want to restore my backup database file. I've got a code working but I the user to enter the file path through an `OpenfileDialog`.

Here is my code:

```vb
restoreDirectory = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
Dim myProcess As New Process()
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.20\bin\"
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
myProcess.Start()
Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter = myProcess.StandardInput
Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql -u root  mssa < " & restoreDirectory & " ")
myStreamWriter.Close()
myProcess.WaitForExit()
myProcess.Close()
```

I'm sure I get the correct path of the file, but it is not working. Am I missing something?

Comment: Don’t use double backslashes in path strings in VB, they’re unnecessary.

Comment: Also, why are you launching `cmd.exe` rather than `mysql` directly? If you insist on doing this (which makes sense for streaming the input, I’ll admit), you should *still* launch `mysql` directly instead of via an input stream of the console (which I’m not sure will work at all) by invoking `cmd.exe -k mysql …`.

Comment: You also need to make sure the account mysql is running as has access to that folder. Might be better to copy the file to location common to that account and the one executing this function, and then restoring it from there.

Comment: try this and replace your pass with YourPass... goodluck
myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -pYourPass < " & restoreDirectory & " ")